# How parsing json data with volley

Tags: android

How can I have the image of this url ..using Volley ??
I am already parsing all the other data .. only the url image...Some help?
This is my code

```
String id =imageName.getText().toString().trim();
    if (id.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...", "Fetching...", false, false);

    String url = Url + imageName.getText().toString().trim();
    Log.d("DIRECT", url);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
```

//                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String response) {
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    String code = "";
    String vende = "";
    String image="";
    String fecha = "";
    String det = "";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);

        code = collegeData.getString("codigo");
        vende = collegeData.getString("articulos");
        fecha = collegeData.getString("detalle");
        det = collegeData.getString("precio");
     //how parsing the url image

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //  texto.setText("Code:\t" + code + "\nVendedeor:\t" + vende + "\nfecha:\t" + fecha + "\ndetalle:\t" + det);
    imageName.setText(code);
    art.setText(vende);
   // imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    deta.setText(fecha);
    pre.setText(det);
```

Log.d("res", String.valueOf(pre)+ String.valueOf(art)+String.valueOf(imageName));

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use a library like picasso and load image like this Picasso.with(context).load("your image url").into(imageView);
to use picasso, add this as dependency compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"

Answer (score 0):

Android Picasso library is a great library to download and also cache images.

https://github.com/square/picasso

Simply you can load image url in ImageView as:

```
Picasso.with(this).load("your_image_url").into(imageView);
```